# OS-independent way of specifying the class path

Tags: java, bash

I have a bash script that bootstraps a Java process. I want it to be able to run on *nix and Cygwin. The problem is the separator in the `-classpath` parameter is different under the two platforms (`:` under *nix and `;` under Windows).

I can't find an environment variable that specifies this separator (same as `$PATH` separator), so is there a better way to solve this than detecting the OS and hard-coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If you write your bootstrap code in Java rather than Bash, you can use the `path.separator` system property.

Otherwise, it's quite normal to see separate launcher scripts for both Unix and Windows.